# Имитация работы сканера+веб приложение

Tags: javascript, php, html, сканирование

Есть система автоматизации для склада написанная на php, mysql javascript, HTML (вообщем браузерная). Есть несколько версий системы для разных типов работы (десктоп, терминал, планшет).
В работе операции сканирования происходят через устройства (терминал сбора данных, ручной сканер подключенный к планшету).В устройствах сканирования настроены префикс и суфикс под систему.

Проверенная возможность подключить сканер к ПК через USB и обрабатывать разные операции всех версий системы. Также есть возможность заменить сканирование ручным вводом кода с клавиатуры.

Для администрирования и тестирования нужны советы или идеи насчет имитации сканирования без использования сканера/ручного ввода с клавиатуры (здесь всегда нужно генерировать штрих-код через другие додатки/ручной ввод занимает время). Есть ли возможность реализовать симитировать сканирование (копировать код для операции с библиотеки и вставить в поле ввода веб додатка)?

Answer (score 0):

5 минут вопросов к яндексу, например "эмулятор сканера штрих кода". И первая же ссылка нам даёт:
https://www.aggsoft.com/com-port-emulator.htm
Впрочем, там ещё много советов, посмотрите сами:
[Алиса, покажи мне эмулятор сканера штрих кода](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D1%8D%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%88%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0&lr=15&clid=1923018)